# What does the symbol ":" mean in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

So why is switch case using colons ":"? Couldn't it be written like this-

```
switch(foo) {
    case 1 {
        do_stuff();
    }
    case 2 {
        do_other_stuff();
    }
    case default {
        do_default_stuff();
    }
}
```

So, why is ":" used with switch and case?

More generally, what does the symbol ":" mean in C and C++?

The only information I found is that it has something to do with `goto`, which I don't think is used much anymore in c and cpp.

Comment: It marks the end of a label — a case label (or `default`) in the case of a switch.  Otherwise, the target for a `goto` statement.  There's nothing special about its use in a `switch` — it marks the end of a label, as you found.  So `case 1:` is a case label; the `:` is the end of the label.  (There are other contexts where a single colon is used; in C++, there are a number of contexts where a double-colon `::` is used.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Colons are usually used in C and C++ grammar to indicate a label: a location where execution can jump to which is not determined by explicit blocks.

Here's what I mean. In an `if` statement, execution will either jump over the first block or the `else` block. In both cases, an entire block is jumped. In a `while` loop, execution jumps to just before the start of the block, or with a `break` statement/failure of the condition, to just outside of the block.

Basically, most jumping around in C and C++ happens on the basis of blocks and keywords.

A `goto` can jump to any arbitrary label within a function (C++ has something to say about how "arbitrarily" you can jump around), regardless of block definitions. While a `switch` statement can only jump to different `case/default` locations within its own block, and only do so to one such location, these locations do not create *blocks* of scope (as much as we'd sometimes like them to). These locations do not define sections of exclusive code; execution passes right through labels (which is why `break` statements are usually used with `case/default`).

In short, `case/default` acts far more like labeled `goto` than normal C or C++ block structures. Therefore, they use the same piece of grammar to indicate them: a colon.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't agree, I wouldn't really mention Duff's Device to anyone, least of all newbies. Manual loop unrolling isn't a very meaningful thing to practice.

Comment: @Lundin no, but that the syntax is such that it allows this to be done

Answer (score 3):

As you read, it's used to designate a target/label for a goto statement to jump to.  For example:

```
 printf("x1\n");
 goto target;
 printf("x2\n");
 target:
 printf("x3\n);
```

Would print out:

```
 x1
 x3
```

It's also used to designate the jump-targets in a switch/case block:

```
 switch(someVal)
 {
    case 1:
       printf("1\n");
    break;

    case 2:
       printf("2\n");
    break;

    default:
       printf("Something else\n");
    break;
 }
```

As for *why* it is used (as opposed to some other character or syntax), the most likely explanation is that the syntax was inherited from the [B language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)), which was the language that C was derived from.  You can see examples of goto and switch/case usage in a B program in [this PDF](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/btut.pdf), and they look very much like the C syntax.

Comment: In BCPL as well.

Answer (score 3):

The : in switch case construct generally marks the end of a case label. That is when a case is defined as case 1: this means that : signifies the end of a label of the case construct inside the case any statements or a method could be executed..

**For eg:**

```
switch(ch)
{
     case 1:// Completion of case 1 label
           printf("Hello");
           break;
     case 2:// Completion of case 2 label
           printf("World");
           break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:` is part of the item known as *labeled-statement* in the syntax. Three different cases exists, C17 6.8.1:

```
labeled-statement:  
  identifier : statement
  case constant-expression : statement
  default : statement
```

The first case `identifier : statement` refers to goto labels, the two other cases to `switch` statements.